# How to convert these objects to valuable information

Tags: python, azure, azure-python-sdk

I have this code to list down the details of Azure Virtual Machines, but I am getting output in this form. How can I change (azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.storage_profile_py3) this kind of output to  valuable information.

> 'name': 'Linux', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',
> 'location': 'eastus', 'tags': None, 'plan': None, 'hardware_profile':
> <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.hardware_profile_py3.HardwareProfile
> object at 0x0000023C8DCFB8B0>, 'storage_profile':
> <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.storage_profile_py3.StorageProfile
> object at 0x0000023C8DCFB0A0>, 'additional_capabilities': None,
> 'os_profile':
> <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.os_profile_py3.OSProfile object
> at 0x0000023C8DCFB4C0>, 'network_profile':
> <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.network_profile_py3.NetworkProfile
> object at 0x0000023C8DCFB910>, 'diagnostics_profile':
> <azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.diagnostics_profile_py3.DiagnosticsProfile
> object at 0x0000023C8DCFB9D0>, 'availability_set': None,
> 'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded', 'instance_view': None,
> 'license_type': None, 'vm_id': 'ef2a71f9-34ac-42d4-ab64-74a18616e635',
> 'resources': None, 'identity': None, 'zones': None

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='6ba20ca0-9eac-47df-a48a-69a935cf3841',
                                         secret='Kqh7Q~gxKhu52LTHbJyGiWGEBRff2Zcfw3O3K', tenant='75df096c-8b72-48e4-9b91-cbf79d87ee3a')
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credential, '8abf0e0e-3787-4d52-92a1-98258b7561cb')

def list_virtual_machines():
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        print(vm)
list_virtual_machines()
```

Comment: Do you want to just print it more "nicely" or do you want to say, convert it to a dictionary? In either case, I would inspect `vm.__dict__` and see what that gives you.

Comment: As they are key value pairs. Look at tbe values tjey are in the form `azure.mngm.compute 0x0000`. So it is not understandable how can I convert to a form that we can Understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below format to get valuable Information about VM

```py
def list_virtual_machines():
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
        print(vm.name)
        print(vm.type)
        print(vm.location)
        print(vm.tags)
        ...
list_virtual_machines()
```

#### Or

Use **[compute_client.virtual_machines.get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm)** to get information about the virtual machine.

#### Example Code follows

```py
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, expand='instanceView') 
print("hardwareProfile") 
print(" vmSize: ", vm.hardware_profile.vm_size) 
print("\nstorageProfile") 
print(" imageReference") 
print(" publisher: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.publisher)
......
```

Comment: Sir I am getting answers but my answers are in the form `<azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.storage_profile_py3.StorageProfile object at 0x0000023C8DCFB0A0>`  How can I convert this form into a type that I can understand it?

Comment: yeah, we can get this information only using this command. You can write a code accordingly.

Comment: Hey @tommyhmt! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?